# How do I print 1st place, 2nd place, etc. up to 5th place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I have a program that reads the top 5 (or all scores and usernames if there are less than 5 people on the leaderboard of a .csv file, called leaderboard2.csv.

However, in the python shell it says this:

```
Here is the Top 5 leaderboard:
Username - Score

123 - 74
example - 45
ok - 36
sample - 36
testing - 30
```

I would like to say 1st place, or 2nd place, so on next to each of the lines above in the shell. E.g. 2nd Place = example - 45.

How do I display it like above (When I do it, it is completely wrong as it displays everyone in the leaderboard next to "1st place = ")

Im using python 3.3.4 by the way.

Thanks in advance, here is my code below:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

scores = Counter()

with open('leaderboard2.csv') as f:
    for name,score in csv.reader(f):

    # convert score into integer
        score = int(score)
        scores[name] = score

# list the top five
print("Here is the Top 5 leaderboard:")
print("Username - Score")
print("")
for name, score in scores.most_common(5):
    print(name + " - " + str(score))
```

Comment: would `enumerate`-ing the most_common suffice?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn `1` into `"1st"`?

Comment: @SethMMorton yes, using the code provided below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this may not be the most elegant of solutions but you could enumerate the list and use that and print out the correct place

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

scores = Counter()

with open('leaderboard2.csv') as f:
    for name,score in csv.reader(f):

    # convert score into integer
        score = int(score)
        scores[name] = score

# list the top five
print("Here is the Top 5 leaderboard:")
print("Username - Score")
print("")
place = 1
for i, v in enumerate(scores.most_common(5)):
  if i == 0:
    print("1st")
  elif i == 1:
    print("2nd")
  print(str(v[0]) + " - " + str(v[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply enumerate the `most_common`.

```
for i, common in enumerate(scores.most_common(5), 1):
    print(i, common[0] + " -", common[1])
```

This of course, will just display the position (1,2,3,4,5), there are [libraries and options available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180845/is-there-a-library-to-convert-integer-to-first-second-third) to convert to first/second/third

Comment: thanks, this prints 1 - example - 15. Can you make it print 1st Place = example - 15?

Comment: @Adam - That is what the link in the question provides assistance with

Comment: I can't use the link because my python (python 3.3.4) doesnt have the module inflect, which is what the link suggests to use.

Comment: @Adam - There are multiple answers on that question, I'd imagine one of the options would be suitable