# Unsupported operand type for sum() function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, mean

I was working on a simple project to get me more acquainted with Python since it's been a while and the new semester has started.

```
import math
count = input('Please enter the number of grades: ')

grade_list = []

while count != 0:
    grade = input('What was the grade for the first test?: ')
    grade_list.append(grade)
    count = int(count) - 1

def mean(x):
    grade_total = int(sum(x))
    grade_count = int(len(x))
    mean = int(grade_total) / int(grade_count)
    return mean

print(mean(grade_list))
```

Here's the error I keep running into:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hattd\Documents\Python Projects\miniproject1.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(mean(grade_list))
  File "C:\Users\hattd\Documents\Python Projects\miniproject1.py", line 12, in mean
    grade_total = int(sum(x))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I thought that turning the variables into integers would stop this from happening? What am I missing here?

Comment: "I thought that turning the variables into integers would stop this from happening?" the objects inside the `list` you are passing to `sum` must be numbers. They are currently strings. You seem to try to do `int(sum(x))` but that's too late - that would convert the *result* of `sum` to an integer (probably not necessary), but the error is occuring inside of `sum`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never "turn the variables into integers". You read a string from the user and append that to `grade_list`, and then you pass `grade_list` (a list of strings) to your `mean` function, where you eventually pass it to `sum` by calling `int(sum(x))`.

You can convert user input to integers by writing `grade_list.append(int(grade))`:

```
grade_list = []

count = int(input('Please enter the number of grades: '))
for _ in range(count):
    grade = input('What was the grade for the first test?: ')
    grade_list.append(int(grade))
```

This gives us a list of integers instead of a list of strings.

I've applied the same logic to the `count` variable as well; this simplifies the code in the `while` loop since we don't need to repeatedly cast `count` to an integer.

If you enter something that isn't an integer at either of these prompts, your code will fail with a `ValueError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/grades.py", line 15, in <module>
    count = int(input("Please enter the number of grades: "))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

If you'd like a friendlier response, you can write a function to read an integer from the user that will re-prompt if they enter an invalid value. Something like:

```
def get_int_with_prompt(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            return val
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid integer.")
```

You would use it like:

```
count = get_int_with_prompt("Please enter the number of grades: ")
```

---

Note that with these changes, you have a bunch of calls to `int` in your `mean` function that are no longer necessary. A cleaned up version of your code might look like:

```
grade_list = []

count = int(input("Please enter the number of grades: "))
for _ in range(count):
    grade = input("What was the grade for the first test?: ")
    grade_list.append(int(grade))


def mean(x):
    grade_total = sum(x)
    grade_count = len(x)
    mean = grade_total / grade_count
    return mean


print(mean(grade_list))
```

---

Of course, there is a `statistics.mean` function, as well:

```
import statistics

grade_list = []

count = int(input("Please enter the number of grades: "))
for _ in range(count):
    grade = input("What was the grade for the first test?: ")
    grade_list.append(int(grade))

print(statistics.mean(grade_list))
```

And consider some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180845/147356) if you'd like to ask for something other than "the first test" every time.

Comment: It works! Thank you for clearing up that misunderstanding for me.

Comment: Glad to help! If this answered your question, please check the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Hey, -1 voter, while I expect that was actually just retaliatory, if you think there's a way I can improve this answer, please let me know!